# VBA to update a column for rows based on being in between two rows of specific values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a new user. I've found the forum to be very useful and I have a question I can't find the answer to by searching online. I am sure it's easy, but I am still learning as I go !

I'm creating a VBA program to automatically create a financial model for my client. The first step is pulling in data from various excel sheets and cleaning / formatting it to a single table. Normally the team would just do it manually, but I would like to leave them with a tool to easily re-run their planning after our project finishes.

One of the inputs is is not very structured and I need to add some new columns to categorize the data for future analysis.

Here is a sample no. of rows of what I am talking about

```
rows   columnA            columnB   columnC
row1   SALES
row2   SegmentA           BRAND1    100
row3   SegmentA           BRAND2    200
row4   SEGMENTA SUB TOTAL
row4   SegmentB           BRAND6    200
row5   SegmentC           BRAND7    300
row6   TOTALSALES
row7
row8   GROSSPROFIT
row9   SegmentA           BRAND1    100
row10  SegmentA           BRAND2    200
row11  SegmentB           BRAND6    200
row12  SegmentC           BRAND7    300
row13  TOTALGROSSPROFIT
```

Thanks to stackoverflow I already found the code to run a for loop through the rows and create a table of totals by Segment.

However because the key figure categories e.g. sales and revenue are not in the columns they are actually in rows my totals are totals across all key figures.

What I think I need to do is somehow write a loop that checks the cell is in a row between the rows for e.g. SALES and TOTALSALES or GROSSPROFIT and TOTALGROSSPROFIT and then update e.g. SALES or GROSSPROFIT. I can then concatenate the key figure and segment e.g. SALES-SEGMENTA and GROSSPROFIT-SEGMENTA and get the right totals.

Update:  A couple of days after posting this I had an idea which appears to work, but still interested to know if there is a better way. In my idea I used FIND to search the 1st column for the titles such as Sales and Gross Profit, I then get the cell address for the start and end points of a range that is relevant to sales, then I used cell.offset to update that info into a new column, as below.

```
Set SalesRangeStart = Range("A:A").Find("Sales", LookIn:=xlValues)
Set SalesRangeFinish = Range("A:A").Find("Sales Total", LookIn:=xlValues)
Range(SalesRangeStart.Address, SalesRangeFinish.Address).Offset(0, 11).Value = "Sales"
```

I've included the code below for the for loop that I am using now to total the data. In the real example the first column of I've called 'BusinessType2' this includes rows like SEGMENT, REVENUE, Blank fields etc. based on BusinessType2 I am trying to sum 4 different columns of numbers representing forecast for 2019,2020,2021 & 2022

I've got no idea how to get the identify which rows is sales vs. gross profit etc. because it's mixed in with the row data. But I have go the loop that totals the segments working.

```
Dim lr As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim BusinessType2 As String
Dim Y2019 As Long
Dim Y2020 As Long
Dim Y2021 As Long
Dim Y2022 As Long
Dim writeRow As Long
lr = 3000

'Set titles for new columns for the output
Range("T1").Value = "BusinessType2"
Range("U1").Value = "Y2019"
Range("V1").Value = "Y2020"
Range("W1").Value = "Y2021"
Range("X1").Value = "Y2020"

' Set initial values for loop - this is the first row of data
BusinessType2 = Range("G11").Value 
Y2019 = Range("K11").Value
Y2020 = Range("L11").Value
Y2021 = Range("M11").Value
Y2022 = Range("N11").Value

' Starting from the 2nd row of data sum by BusinessType2
For j = 12 To lr + 1
  If Range("G" & j).Value = BusinessType2 Then         
    Y2019 = Y2019 + Range("K" & j).Value
    Y2020 = Y2020 + Range("L" & j).Value
    Y2021 = Y2021 + Range("M" & j).Value
    Y2022 = Y2022 + Range("N" & j).Value
' The data has a lot of blank rows so we skip them
  ElseIf Range("G" & j).Value = "" Then
    GoTo NextIteration
' After totalling for 1 instance of BusinessType2 write the output
  Else                                                                                                         
    writeRow = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
    Range("T" & writeRow).Value = BusinessType2     
    Range("U" & writeRow).Value = Y2019                      
    Range("V" & writeRow).Value = Y2020
    Range("W" & writeRow).Value = Y2021
    Range("X" & writeRow).Value = Y2022
    BusinessType2 = Range("G" & j).Value                 
    Y2019 = Range("K" & j).Value                                   
    Y2020 = Range("L" & j).Value
    Y2021 = Range("M" & j).Value
    Y2022 = Range("N" & j).Value
  End If
NextIteration:
  Next j
End Sub
```

Current loop is working for summing the segments, but the totals span across different key figures e.g. Revenue, Gross Profit, Overheads, EBIT etc. and I need them to total separately.

Comment: not any help, but I would avoid using variables which are close to excel ranges like Y2022 etc.

Comment: Hi @Nathan_Sav - Thanks for the tip, I had read to be careful of that, but it slipped my mind, thanks, I'll try to avoid developing bad habits.